# Mix-blend-mode keep specific color

Tags: mix-blend-mode

I looked a lot, tried a lot of codes, but I can't find any solution.

As I suspect with mix-blend color we can't create specific solid color, if the background is image.

Is it possible the "recreate" the mix-blend-mode effect [changing effect only if the text is over the image] with JavaScript? Or any other solution?

[image]